# trying access an array in an Api but is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I am trying to access an array in an Api but unfortunately it not returning anything.  The line is the `<p>` tag for the borders.  Below is my code:

```
// import './App.css';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function CountryDetail({ match }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
    console.log(match);
  }, []);

  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    try {
      const fetchCountry = await fetch(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}`
      );
      const country = await fetchCountry.json();
      setCountry(country[0]);
      console.log(country[0]);
    } catch {
      // leave state alone
    }
  };

  return (
    country && (
      <div>
        <h1> Name: {country.name} </h1>{" "}
        <p> Native Name: {country.nativeName} </p>{" "}
        <p> Region: {country.region} </p>{" "}
        <p>
          {" "}
          Languages: {country.languages.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}{" "}
        </p>{" "}
        <p>
          {" "}
          Borders: {country.borders.map(({ border }) => border).join(", ")}{" "}
        </p>{" "}
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default CountryDetail;
```

I get the line above is an object in the Api.  However, for the array I don't seem to map through the array.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `country.borders` is an array, you could achieve your mapping with:

```
Borders: {country.borders.join(', ')}
```

I don't think there is a need to use .map as you are